# How to copy one NSMutablearray to another NSMutablearray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I know that you guys may feel that this is repetitive question. But I'm screwed up with this issue with my project. 
Now moving to the issue, I have taken an `NSMutableArray` named `arr1` that contains string values such as `@"34"`, `@"40"` and so on. Now, I have second `NSMutableArray` named `arr2`. I have already tried below code.

```
[arr1 initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
arr2 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr1 copyItems:YES] autorelease];
```

Then, I tried

```
NSString  *no = [arr2 objectAtIndex:0];
tst.text = no;
```

However, it gives me no value in my textbox.
If any1 can help me out with this would be great help.

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%@",no);` show in the Console?

Comment: Have you tested if your text field is not `nil`.

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code? `[arr1 initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];` this looks very dodgy to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [i want to copy a mutable array into another mutable array in iphone sdk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938366/i-want-to-copy-a-mutable-array-into-another-mutable-array-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arr1 might be nil. It should be

```
arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
[arr1 initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
```

makes no sense, what you probably want is to use the `NSMutableArray`:

```
NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
NSMutableArray *arr2 = [arr1 mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"arr1: %p, %@", arr1, arr1);
NSLog(@"arr2: %p, %@", arr2, arr2);
```

NSLog output:

```
arr1: 0x7924c50, (
                 1,
                 2
                 )
arr2: 0x7924f00, (
                 1,
                 2
                 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `arr1` must be `nil` otherwise you would crash, but more to the point you are creating the `NSMutableArray` incorrectly:

You should not really do `alloc` and `init` on separate lines

```
NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray alloc];

NSLog(@"%@", [myArray class]);

//=> __NSPlaceholderArray
```

In this case the `myArray` pointer is pointing at a flyweight of type `__NSPlaceholderArray` which is most likely not what you want. You would prefer:

```
---------------------------------------

myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@", [myArray class]);

//=> __NSArrayM
```

---

You will also crash if you do have a legitimate `NSMutableArray` and you call `initWithArray:`  with:

```
[NSMutableArray initWithCapacity:]: method only defined for abstract class.
```

This is because the method is most likely defined on `__NSPlaceholderArray`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying `[arr2 objectAtIndex:0]` in the same method where `arr2` is being created?

Maybe the problem is that you are using `autorelease` on your `arr2`. So, in other methods it may have lost its values.

I tried the following and it works for me:

```
NSMutableArray * arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", nil];
NSMutableArray * arr2 = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arr1 copyItems:YES] autorelease];
NSString * no = [arr2 objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", no);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to tia's answer: you need to allocate it first.

The method 'mutableCopy' will create a copy of the array, not of the elements inside it.
You could create a new immutable array with 'initWithArray:arr1 copyItems:YES' and subsequently create a mutable version of it by calling 'mutableCopy'.:

```
NSArray *arr1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
NSMutableArray arr2 = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: arr1 copyItems:YES] mutableCopy];
```